# Root file properties

Tags: eclipse, installation, repository

I followed [this](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm) help page to add folder to a features based product. In build.properties file I added:

> root=iwrepo

[image]

'iwrepo' corresponds to a folder with sub-folders residing in a feature where the above mentioned properties file is. After the build, I get only folders under 'iwrepo' folder moved to Eclipse install directory (annogen,antlr, etc), not what I expected - 'iwrepo' folder with its sub-folders.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation

> Similar to the "root" and "root." properties, except that instead of being copied into the root of the eclipse install, files and folders are instead copied into the given subfolder.

Instead of **root=iwrepo**, I need to use **root.folder.iwrepo=iwrepo**. This correctly subfolders folders under iwrepo.